# form to redirect to save cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cookies

Hey guys i have this code;

```
<Script language="JavaScript">
function goto(form) { var index=form.select.selectedIndex
if (form.select.options[index].value != "0") {
location=form.select.options[index].value;}}
</SCRIPT>
<FORM NAME="form1">
<SELECT NAME="select" ONCHANGE="goto(this.form)" SIZE="1">
<OPTION VALUE="">-------Choose a Selection-------
<OPTION VALUE="/">Home
<OPTION VALUE="page.htm">Area 1
<OPTION VALUE="page.htm">Area2
<OPTION VALUE="page.htm">Area 3 
<OPTION VALUE="page.htm">Area 4
<OPTION VALUE="page.htm">Area 5</SELECT>
</FORM>
```

What I want to do is generate a cookie when the user clicks one of these, and then when they go back to my website it will redirect to that page if the cookie exist. Basically this is going to be a region of interest. Though I want it so they can go to other regions if they want to search other areas.

I do not know what I would need can someone help me understand the cookie ui and how i would implement it to this code?

If you need any other information please just ask i'm willing to answer and give more info

Answer (score 2):

You can call this function on

```
 <SELECT NAME="select" ONCHANGE="doThis(someParameters)" SIZE="1">
```

Then include these javascript functions

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function doThis(someVal){
if (someVal==1){
setCookie("myCookie",someVal, someTime);
window.location.href = "page1.htm"; // if u wish to redirect then itself
}
//similarly for others 
if (someVal==2){

}
}
```